# Faster or better way to transpose a bytearray into seperate values

Tags: ctypes

I have a bytearray filled with "c-type" reversed order data like sint32_t but also sint24_t. A 24-bit signed value needs to be converted into a integer. Python handles negative values as a value with a minus sign and c uses the signed bit to indicate a negative value.

So I came up changing it to 32-bit first:

```
raw = bytearray('\x89\x00\x23') 
val = (ord(raw[0:1]) | (ord(raw[1:2])<<8) | (ord(raw[2:3])<<16) )
if ( (val & 0x00800000L) > 0):
    val |= 0xFF000000L
```

This works however now I have a 32-bit signed value. I still need it to become a negative value in python. So I came up with:

```
import ctypes
p_val = ctypes.c_int32(val).value
```

This will convert it in the correct way.
I would like this to be a bit more efficient and faster. Is there any way to rewrite this in something that is much faster. I need to create 7 values like this per iteration. I read something about "memoryview"?

Anyone?

Comment: Getting the 2's complement signed value doesn't require ctypes. The conversion from bytes can be implemented with the `struct` module, but the buffer needs to be sign extended to 4 bytes. For example: `val = struct.unpack('<i', raw + b'\xff' if raw[-1] > 127 else raw + b'\x00')[0]`. In Python 2 this depends on `raw` being a `bytearray`, for which indexing returns an integer byte value. In Python 3 you can implement this conversion more simply as `val = int.from_bytes(raw, 'little', signed=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

Various options:

```
import struct

MAX_INT24 = (1<<23)-1
BIAS_INT24 = (1<<24)

def int24(raw):
    val = raw[0] | (raw[1] << 8) | (raw[2] << 16)
    # val = struct.unpack('<i',raw + b'\x00')[0]   # Another option
    return val if val <= MAX_INT24 else val - BIAS_INT24

raws = [b'\xff\xff\x7f',
        b'\xff\xff\xff',
        b'\xfe\xff\xff']

for raw in raws:
    print(int24(raw))
    print(int.from_bytes(raw,'little',signed=True)) # Python 3 only
```

Output:

```
8388607
8388607
-1
-1
-2
-2
```